# PHP: combine several arrays in associative one

Tags: php, arrays

I have this arrays:

```
$main = array("Name","Age");

$fname =array("Peter","Ben","Joe");

$age = array("35","37","43");
```

I need to combine it. Output array must be:

```
[0] =>
   [Name] => [Peter]
   [Age] => [35]
[1] =>
   [Name] => [Ben]
   [Age] => [37]
[2] =>
   [Name] => [Joe]
   [Age] => [43]
```

And so on. I have tried array_combine, but it gives an error, cuz `$main` contains only two values, array_merge combine arrays not exactly i want, it adds any next array to the end of result array.

How to solve my issue? Help , please!

Comment: Post Your Code.. Let's see what you have tried..

Comment: Start with a simple `foreach`

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should do:

```
$result = array_map(
    function () use ($main) {
        return array_combine($main, func_get_args());
    },
    $fname,
    $age
);
```

PHP 5.6+ allows this nicer syntax for the callback:

```
function (...$vals) use ($main) {
    return array_combine($main, $vals);
}
```

Though I would first point out that this is a rather peculiar dataset to end up with, and you should maybe see if there's something you can do *before* this to get your data in better shape so you don't need to bend over backwards like this in the first place.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly i want!

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_map` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use($main){ 
    return array_combine($main, $v);
}, array_map(null, $fname, $age));

print_r($result);
```

The same can be achieved with regular `foreach` loop + `array_combine` function:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($fname as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = array_combine($main, [$v, $age[$k]]);
}
```

---

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Peter
            [Age] => 35
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ben
            [Age] => 37
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Joe
            [Age] => 43
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want :

```
$newArray = [];
$main = array("Name","Age");

$fname =array("Peter","Ben","Joe");

$age = array("35","37","43");
$newArray = array_combine($fname, $age);
$array = [];
foreach($newArray as $key => $value) {
  $array[] = [
      $main[0] => $key,
      $main[1] => $value
  ];
}
var_dump($array);
```